# Mysql search and replace query - escape format

Tags: mysql

I am using a mysql search and replace like the line below:

```
UPDATE ibf_forums_posts SET post = REPLACE(post, "_blank", "external");
```

However, I don't know how to properly use an escape clause for entries that use quotes in them.  For example, if I am trying to search and replace target="_blank" with target="_blank" rel="noopener"

This, for example, does not work:

```
UPDATE ibf_forums_posts SET post = REPLACE(post, "target=\"_blank\"", "target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\"");
```

Any help on how to construct such mysql queries would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use single-quotes, `'`, you will not need to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

That worked, thank you! The query would look like this:

```
UPDATE ibf_forums_posts SET post = REPLACE(post, 'target="_blank"', 'target="_blank" rel="nofollow"');
```